# Can I keep the Screen Sharing app from showing the menu bar?

Tags: macos, fullscreen, screen-sharing

I need to use Mac OS X's screen sharing app a lot to access a remote system (also using Mac OS X). I'm new to Macs and I keep having the following problem:

If I leave my mouse cursor within roughly a fifth of the top of the screen, OS X thinks I want to exit fullscreen mode and shows the OS X menu bar.

This is very annoying as the only options I can find will allow me to choose having the remote display get resized (which is terrible if I'm hovering over a button which was just about to click) or part of my screen gets covered by the menu bar.

How can I stop the OS from trying to help me until I push the cursor into the farthest pixel in the upper right hand corner (or something like that) so that I can use the machine as a thin-client and not deal with the local system? Is there a way I could create a separate user account that only displays that application as if there's no Finder?

Before suggesting another client: I've found that you really need to use the default one in OS X or it is a poor experience.

Answer (score 1):

Something that made this less annoying/painful for me was to:

- Turn scaling on
- Set remote monitor resolution to match exactly client resolution (laptop)
- Set to follow cursor continuously

This seems to trigger the top bar pull-down less frequently, but it still happens.

Another workaround would be not using fullscreen mode, and use maximized mode instead, but that's no fun!